# Intel C++ linker manifest error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, manifest, intel-composer

I'm try to build project, previously designed for MSVS 2013 C++ Compiler with Intel C++ Compiler 2015. I had created new project configuration called `'Unicode ICC Release'` as a copy of standard `'Unicode Release'` configuration. And after that I had changed the Platform toolset with Intel Compiler. Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
Error   9   error c101008c: Failed to read the manifest from the resource of file "Project.dll". The operation failed.  Project\mt.exe  Project
```

The command line of Intel linker is looks like that:

```
/OUT:"../../Path1/Project.dll" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"Path2\\Pdb\Project.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE /LARGEADDRESSAWARE /IMPLIB:"../Path3/Project.lib" /DEBUG /DLL /MACHINE:X86 /OPT:REF /SAFESEH /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:NO /ManifestFile:"Path4\Project.dll.intermediate.manifest" /OPT:ICF /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"../Lib.Win32" /TLBID:1
```

And `Project.dll` really doesn't contain manifest!

Have any ideas how to fix this behaviour?

UPD:

MSVS linker diagnostic output:

```
1>  Finished searching libraries
1>  
1>  Invoking mt.exe:
1>   /verbose
1>   /out:"C:\Users\LOMONO~1.MIN\AppData\Local\Temp\lnk{A7C6A6FD-79FB-46A7-8AF9-F8FC8729046E}.tmp"
1>   /manifest
1>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\Include\Manifest\dpiaware.manifest"
1>   C:\Users\LOMONO~1.MIN\AppData\Local\Temp\lnk{F104CF0A-974F-45E5-97C2-C71C4265AE20}.tmp
1>  Microsoft (R) Manifest Tool version 6.1.7716.0
1>  
1>  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation 2009. 
1>  
1>  All rights reserved.
1>  
1>  
1>  Invoking rc.exe:
1>   /v
1>   /x
1>   /fo
1>   "C:\Users\LOMONO~1.MIN\AppData\Local\Temp\lnk{E7AC97BB-2CBB-4C34-8140-C1BA750D564E}.tmp"
1>   "C:\Users\LOMONO~1.MIN\AppData\Local\Temp\lnk{707AEC66-9E09-4CBF-92FF-E00B822645AC}.tmp"
1>  Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.1.7600.16385
1>  
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>  
1>  
1>  Creating C:\Users\LOMONO~1.MIN\AppData\Local\Temp\lnk{E7AC97BB-2CBB-4C34-8140-C1BA750D564E}.tmp
1>  
1>  Using codepage 1251 as default
1>  
1>  C:\Users\LOMONO~1.MIN\AppData\Local\Temp\lnk{707AEC66-9E09-4CBF-92FF-E00B822645AC}.tmp.
1>  Writing 24:2,   lang:0x409, size 334
1>  
1>  Invoking cvtres.exe:
1>   /machine:x86
1>   /verbose
1>   /out:"C:\Users\LOMONO~1.MIN\AppData\Local\Temp\lnk{FEB0B0CB-A8E7-4359-BD8B-AB1996E47436}.tmp"
1>   /readonly
1>   "Win32\Unicode Release\Version.res"
1>   "Win32\Unicode Release\Project.res"
1>   "C:\Users\LOMONO~1.MIN\AppData\Local\Temp\lnk{E7AC97BB-2CBB-4C34-8140-C1BA750D564E}.tmp"
1>  Microsoft (R) Windows Resource To Object Converter Version 12.00.21005.1
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>  
1>  adding resource. type:VERSION, name:1, language:0x0000, flags:0x30, size:568
1>  adding resource. type:STRING, name:7, language:0x0409, flags:0x1030, size:48
1>  adding resource. type:MANIFEST, name:2, language:0x0409, flags:0x30, size:334
```

Intel xlink output:

```
1>  Finished searching libraries
1>  
1>  Invoking cvtres.exe:
1>   /machine:x86
1>   /verbose
1>   /out:"C:\Users\LOMONO~1.MIN\AppData\Local\Temp\lnk{3DBDEC74-99D1-4C46-8274-068BDB33431D}.tmp"
1>   /readonly
1>   "Win32\Unicode ICC Release\Version.res"
1>   "Win32\Unicode ICC Release\Project.res"
1>  Microsoft (R) Windows Resource To Object Converter Version 12.00.21005.1
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>  
1>  adding resource. type:VERSION, name:1, language:0x0000, flags:0x30, size:568
1>  adding resource. type:STRING, name:7, language:0x0409, flags:0x1030, size:48
```

Comment: Mt.exe always has a very hard time accessing an executable file that was created a couple of milliseconds ago.   Try disabling the typical shrink-wrapped malware that runs on a programmer's machine and tell your virus scanner to exclude the build directory.  Uninstall it completely if is something aggressively flawed like Avast.

Comment: I have tried, but it didn't help. Generate Manifest field in Linker Properties filled with Yes (/MANIFEST), but manifest is missing.